# How do I select a table using a variable with db_query()?

Tags: database

I'm trying to find records from a table based on a variable that is grabbed from user submission. This is my query:

```
$field = t('field_data_' . variable_get('tabbed_content_field'));
$fieldValue = t(variable_get('tabbed_content_field') . '_value');
$query = db_query('SELECT :fieldValue FROM {:field}', array(':field' => $field, ':fieldValue' => $fieldValue));
```

However, whenever I run this query I get the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''field_data_field_news_release_date'' at line 2: SELECT
>   :fieldValue FROM {:field}; Array ( [:field] =>
>   field_data_field_news_release_date [:fieldValue] =>
>   field_news_release_date_value )

I can retrieve the records successfully with:

```
$query = db_query('SELECT ' . $fieldValue . ' FROM { ' . $field . '}');
```

However, as I understand it this would be insecure.

Does anyone know why the first query won't work?

Comment: As a side note, you don't use `t()` for strings that don't need to be translated. The name of a database table, or a database field is not something that needs to be translated; the "node" table is always the "node" table, independently from the language currently enabled for the site.

Comment: @kiamlaluno ah right thks for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the reasons the new query builder exists in Drupal 7, so you can dynamically substitute parts of the query:

```
$table_name = 'the_table';
$field_name = 'a_field';
$query = db_select($table_name)->fields($table_name, array($field_name));
```

Using `db_query()` you only get parameter replacement, which would only be applicable to substitutions in `WHERE` conditions. This means that you cannot use `db_query()` to replace table names, the names of fields selected, etc., only `WHERE` conditions.

Have a look at the [`db_select()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) docs for more in-depth examples, including how to add conditions to the dynamic query.

Comment: Great thanks very much Clive - that worked for me. Does the db_select function automatically sanitise potentially malicious data entry?

Comment: @StephenYoung It does, the Drupal database layer is essentially a wrapper around PDO so you get all of the parametized query goodness built right in. The only way to use it unsafely is like the second example in your question, which as you rightly said would potentially be open to exploit.

Comment: @StephenYoung Data passed to the database API are sanitized.